# No module named 'virtualenvwrapper' suddenly while in a virtual environment session

Tags: python, tmux, virtualenvwrapper

I was using `virtualenvwrapper` just fine when suddenly I started getting

```
Error while finding spec for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (<class 'ImportError'>: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
```

and I'm really confused why this is happening? What's changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I changed virtual environments in a normal terminal and then logged into a `tmux` session my `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` environment variable was set to my virtual environment path. As such,

```
echo $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON
/home/user/.virtualenvs/venv/bin/python
```

when it should have been the instance of python that had `virtualenvwrapper` installed original.

In my particular case the system python path was the python instance that had `virtualenvwrapper` installed originally.

As such I just ran:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
```

and `virtualenvwrapper` works once more.

and now `workon` works as expected.